# Python-sniffing IP packets

Tags: python, tcp, udp, ip, raw-sockets

What is the appropriate way in python to sniff all IP packets in real time? I'm interested in getting the raw packet data.

I've read that raw sockets are supposed to let you read some packets but didn't quite get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it make sense to use [pylibpcap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibpcap). Which is wrapper on Linux [libcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) application for package capturing.